# Google cloud DNS record set doesn't work

Tags: dns, google-cloud-platform

I have a back-end service on Google cloud, which I access through a Google cloud load-balancer with a static IP for front-end and port 80 (do not get any ideas, I am a developer with very basic knowledge of networking).

For accessing this service through a domain name (as a sub-domain of apps.googleusercontent.com, not custom domain), I created a zone (in cloud DNS) and then an A-Type record set with the IP of the load balancer. I get a 404 (google 404 page) on this new Domain.

I did a nslookup on new domain name and the IP returned was different than the loadbalancer IP. NSLookup returned another IP when I tried again after 30 minutes.

Is this the right way to setup the domain?

P.S. The back-end is a Kubernetes service.

For creating zone, I used this DNS suffix : apps.googleusercontent.com

Comment: please check whether you are getting services endpoints using kubectl

Comment: I can access the back-end service using the LoadBalancer IP.

Comment: please check ttl set for dns record reduce it to 1 min and try again

Comment: also make sure you update ns records in your domain  registered admin  panel

Answer (score 0):

The "apps.googleusercontent.com" domain is a generic domain owned by Google. You aren't supposed to be able to modify the IP of it.

When you running a "Nslookup" on the domain name it is returning an IP of Google. That's why when you try to access through the load balancer IP directly it works.

You should add an CNAME record that point to your custom domain to the domain .